# Use Bootstrap 4 dropdown with angular 4

Tags: html, angular, data-binding, angular4-forms

I wanted to use custom styling in HTML selection list. Since HTML  does not allow (very minimal styling) to put custom styles due to some limitations. I used Bootstap 4 dropdown which mocks the HTML selection list behavior. I was able to add custom style by doing it.

Now I am having problem in selecting an item from dropdown and sending it back to angular component using this approach.

Here is my initial solution using HTML Selection list. I was able to bind color name with angular model using it.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
         <strong class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Select Color * &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
      </div>
      <select class="form-control s-styled" [(ngModel)]="productToEdit.colorOptionId" (change)="onOptionChange($event.target.value, optionGroupCode.Color)">
      <option>Please Select Color</option>
      <option *ngFor="let color of colorOptions">{{color.optionName}}
      </option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the solution using Bootstrap 4 dropdown. I am able to render dropdown neatly. But I am having problems in binding the selected color name with model. 
I want to use the selected color name inside my model as shown in image below.

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="productToEdit.parentProductId > 0">
   <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
         <strong class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Select Color * &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
      </div>
      <span type="button" class="form-control" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" #colorSpan>Choose Color
      </span>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="max-height: 1000%; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
         <div *ngFor="let color of colorOptions">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="dropdown-item text-muted">
                     <span class="circle {{color.optionName.replace(' ' , '-')}}" style="margin-left:3px"></span> &nbsp;
                     <span class="text-muted small lowercase" style="align-items:center;">{{color.optionName}}</span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: can show image of your output?

Comment: @Nihal added image of bootstrap dropdown. The selected color should be displayed and replace "choose color" and also be reflected back to model.